# bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I am receiving this error when I am trying to install Django. I set up the virtual environment and I activated it. I noticed that other users seem to get the `^M` that is causing them issues, but I think mine may be a different issue. This is the error:

```
(venv) $ pip install django
bash: ~/Documents/Coding Projects/Python/blog/venv/bin/pip: 
~/Documents/Coding: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't use a path where a directory name has a space in it.

Comment: Hey! I thought you should know you are amazing! Thank you!